# How can I write a list of random generated numbers to a file?

Tags: java, random, filewriter

This is what I have so far. I am having issues with getting the `File Writer` to work.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Sort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    int q = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            int foo = rand.nextInt();
            System.out.println(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

I will be using the file to sort later.

Comment: "I am having issues with getting the File Writer to work" I don't see any FileWriter in your code. This is first problem you should fix. We can't tell you what you are doing wrong without seeing how are you using this class.

Comment: You have the logic of your program down. You know you need a FileWriter; You'll have to do some reading up on how to use that class. In a nutshell, you're going to have to create a FileWriter object with whichever constructor you want. Once you have a FileWriter object, just start writing to it instead of printing to System.out.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write a list of random generated numbers to a file?

For example like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files
            .newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {

        for (PrimitiveIterator.OfInt ints = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                .ints().limit(10_000).iterator(); ints.hasNext();) {
            writer.write(String.valueOf(ints.nextInt()));
            writer.newLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope you see how it works. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html has more information.

Comment: Ok, I now need to read in those numbers and sort them using varying sorting algorithms. The algorithms I am using are from my text book, however I am a little confused how to put in the FileReader in the code. The code consists of sorting an array and the file as I know is not an array. I know there are multiple ways to do this I just don't know if I should create a new class for the file reader or just put it into each of the sorting algorithms.